# Navigator pop after display snackbar flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation, flutter-web, flutter-test

I would like to pop my screen after my SnackBar is terminated.

How do ?

```
Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
                  SnackBar(
                    backgroundColor: Colors.pink,
                    content: Text('Successfull !'),
                    duration: Duration(seconds: 5),
                  ),
                );
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `closed` `then`

[SnackBarClosedReason](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SnackBarClosedReason-class.html)

```
Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
  SnackBar(
    backgroundColor: Colors.pink,
    content: Text('Successfull !'),
    duration: Duration(seconds: 5),
  ),
).closed.then((SnackBarClosedReason reason) {
  Navigator.of(context).pop();
});
```